Arrows are not working or showing for table content that is not displayed in the initial viewport
Some of the content career route connections do not work for the table's last row. So, I'm wondering that the information that we need to scroll to click on is experiencing arrow pathway connection issues. Because the first viewport content arrow for both the second and third columns works exceptionally well. However, those material that are outside of the first view port or that require us to scroll down to view are experiencing problems.
When I select Entry-level Positions, Research Roles, Doctorate or PhD in Science. Issues are evident more clearly.
To further understand the issues, following screenshots are supplied -  
I tried to remedy it by updating the route positions dynamically based on the scroll event to guarantee that your items are precisely positioned, but it didn't work either.
My code -


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const credentials = document.querySelectorAll(".credential li");
  const careers = document.querySelectorAll(".career li");
  const table = document.querySelector(".table-container");

  function resetUI() {
    // Reset all elements
    credentials.forEach((c) => {
      c.classList.remove("selected");
      c.classList.remove("disabled");
    });
    careers.forEach((c) => {
      c.classList.remove("selected");
      c.classList.remove("disabled");
    });

    // Clear all arrows from the SVG
    const svg = document.getElementById("arrows");
    while (svg.firstChild) {
      svg.removeChild(svg.firstChild);
    }

    // Update the SVG dimensions to cover the entire table
    const tableRect = table.getBoundingClientRect();
    svg.setAttribute("width", tableRect.width);
    svg.setAttribute("height", tableRect.height);

    // Re-append the arrowhead marker
    const marker = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "marker"
    );
    marker.setAttribute("id", "arrowhead");
    marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "10");
    marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "7");
    marker.setAttribute("refX", "0");
    marker.setAttribute("refY", "3.5");
    marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto");
    const arrowhead = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "polygon"
    );
    arrowhead.setAttribute("points", "0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7");
    arrowhead.setAttribute("fill", "orange");
    marker.appendChild(arrowhead);
    svg.appendChild(marker);
  }

  function drawArrowFromCertificateToCareer(fromElement, toElement) {
    const svg = document.getElementById("arrows");
    const fromRect = fromElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const toRect = toElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate positions relative to the table container
    const fromX = fromRect.right - svgRect.left; // Right side of the certificate
    const fromY = fromRect.top + fromRect.height / 2 - svgRect.top; // Middle of the certificate
    const toX = toRect.left - svgRect.left; // Left side of the career
    const toY = toRect.top + toRect.height / 2 - svgRect.top; // Middle of the career

    const arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    arrow.setAttribute("x1", fromX);
    arrow.setAttribute("y1", fromY);
    arrow.setAttribute("x2", toX);
    arrow.setAttribute("y2", toY);
    arrow.setAttribute("stroke", "orange");
    arrow.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1.0");
    arrow.setAttribute("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

    svg.appendChild(arrow);
  }

  function drawCircularArrows(fromCareer, credentialIds) {
    const svg = document.getElementById("arrows");
    const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    const careerRect = fromCareer.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Sort credentials by their vertical position
    const sortedCredentials = credentialIds
      .map((id) => document.getElementById(id))
      .filter((el) => el !== null)
      .sort(
        (a, b) => a.getBoundingClientRect().top - b.getBoundingClientRect().top
      );

    // Draw arrows between credentials
    for (let i = 0; i < sortedCredentials.length - 1; i++) {
      const fromRect = sortedCredentials[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      const toRect = sortedCredentials[i + 1].getBoundingClientRect();

      const arrow = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "line"
      );
      arrow.setAttribute(
        "x1",
        fromRect.left - svgRect.left + fromRect.width / 2
      );
      arrow.setAttribute("y1", fromRect.bottom - svgRect.top);
      arrow.setAttribute("x2", toRect.left - svgRect.left + toRect.width / 2);
      arrow.setAttribute("y2", toRect.top - svgRect.top);
      arrow.setAttribute("stroke", "orange");
      arrow.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
      arrow.setAttribute("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

      svg.appendChild(arrow);
    }

    // Draw arrow from last credential to career
    if (sortedCredentials.length > 0) {
      const lastCredRect =
        sortedCredentials[sortedCredentials.length - 1].getBoundingClientRect();

      const arrow = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "line"
      );
      arrow.setAttribute(
        "x1",
        lastCredRect.left - svgRect.left + lastCredRect.width / 2
      );
      arrow.setAttribute("y1", lastCredRect.bottom - svgRect.top);
      arrow.setAttribute("x2", careerRect.left - svgRect.left); // Point to the left edge of the career span
      arrow.setAttribute(
        "y2",
        careerRect.top - svgRect.top + careerRect.height / 2
      ); // Point to the vertical middle of the career span
      arrow.setAttribute("stroke", "orange");
      arrow.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
      arrow.setAttribute("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

      svg.appendChild(arrow);
    }
  }

  function highlightRelatedItems(selectedItem, _items, dataAttribute) {
    const relatedItems = selectedItem.dataset[dataAttribute].split(",");

    // Highlight related items
    relatedItems.forEach((itemId) => {
      const itemElement = document.getElementById(itemId);
      if (itemElement) {
        itemElement.classList.remove("disabled");
        itemElement.classList.add("selected");
        if (selectedItem.closest(".credential")) {
          // Draw arrow from credential to career
          drawArrowFromCertificateToCareer(selectedItem, itemElement);
        } else {
          // Draw circular arrows for careers
          drawCircularArrows(selectedItem, relatedItems);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Add event listeners to credentials (Certificate, Degree or Credential column)
  credentials.forEach((credential) => {
    credential.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent click event from propagating to the document

      // Reset all elements
      resetUI();

      // Highlight the selected credential and disable others
      credential.classList.add("selected");
      credentials.forEach((c) => {
        if (c !== credential) {
          c.classList.add("disabled");
        }
      });

      // Highlight related careers and draw arrows from credential to career
      highlightRelatedItems(credential, careers, "related");

      // Disable unselected careers
      careers.forEach((c) => {
        if (!c.classList.contains("selected")) {
          c.classList.add("disabled");
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Add event listeners to careers
  careers.forEach((career) => {
    career.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent click event from propagating to the document

      // Reset all elements
      resetUI();

      // Highlight the selected career and disable others
      career.classList.add("selected");
      careers.forEach((c) => {
        if (c !== career) {
          c.classList.add("disabled");
        }
      });

      // Retrieve related credentials from the data-related attribute
      const relatedCredentials = career.dataset.related.split(",");

      // Draw the circular arrows from career to credentials and back
      drawCircularArrows(career, relatedCredentials);

      // Highlight related credentials
      highlightRelatedItems(career, credentials, "related");

      // Disable unrelated credentials
      credentials.forEach((c) => {
        if (!c.classList.contains("selected")) {
          c.classList.add("disabled");
        }
      });
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", resetUI);
  window.addEventListener("resize", resetUI);
});
/* Improved typography and color scheme */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f7fa;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Container with rounded corners and subtle shadow */

.table-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
  /* For positioning the arrows SVG */
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* Table styling with alternating row colors */

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

table thead tr th:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}

table thead tr th:nth-child(2),
table tbody tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 40%;
}

th {
  background-color: #f0f4f8;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}


/* Rounded corners for first and last cells in a row */

tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}


/* Remove list-style and add styling for credential and career items */

.credential ul,
.career ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.credential li,
.career li {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.credential li:hover,
.career li:hover {
  background-color: #e8f0fe;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Selected state with color highlight */

.selected {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* Disabled state */

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Education level styling */

.education-level {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}


/* Color scheme for education levels */

.high-school {
  background-color: #e8eaf6;
}

.one-year-college {
  background-color: #fff3e0;
}

.two-years-college {
  background-color: #e0f2f1;
}

.four-years-college {
  background-color: #fce4ec;
}

.six-years-college {
  background-color: #e1f5fe;
}

.six-plus-years-college {
  background-color: #fff8e1;
}


/* Arrows SVG styling */

#arrows {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* Responsive design */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .table-container {
    padding: 16px;
  }
  table {
    min-width: 400px;
  }
  table thead tr th:nth-child(2),
  table tbody tr th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 46%;
  }
  table tbody tr td:first-child {
    padding: 84px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td:first-child span {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Prevent the text from wrapping */
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    /* Adjust alignment */
  }
  table td,
  table th {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(2),
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  th,
  td {
    padding: 8px;
  }
  td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .credential li,
  .career li {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
  #arrows line {
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    /* Thinner lines for small screens */
  }
  /* Adjust the size of arrowheads */
  marker polygon {
    points: "0 0, 5 1.75, 0 3.5";
    /* Smaller arrowhead size */
  }
}

@media (hover: none) {
  .credential li,
  .career li {
    padding: 12px 8px;
  }
}


/* Smooth transitions for all interactive elements */

a,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/* Optimize white space */

li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
<main>
  <div class="table-container" role="table" aria-label="Career Pathways Table">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Education Level</th>
          <th scope="col">Certificate, Degree or Credential</th>
          <th scope="col">Career</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="education-level high-school"><span>High School</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="high-school-diploma" data-related="assistant,technician,specialist">High School Diploma
              </li>
              <li id="vocational-certificate" data-related="assistant">Vocational Certificate</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="entry-level" data-related="associate-degree,certificate,vocational-certificate,phd-science">
                Entry-level positions</li>
              <li id="assistant" data-related="high-school-diploma,vocational-certificate">Assistant roles
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="education-level one-year-college"><span>1 Year College</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="certificate" data-related="assistant,technician">Certificate</li>
              <li id="technical-certificate" data-related="technician">Technical Certificate</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="assistant" data-related="certificate,technical-certificate">Assistant roles</li>
              <li id="technician" data-related="certificate,technical-certificate">Technician roles
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="education-level two-years-college"><span>2 Years College</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="associate-degree" data-related="professional,specialist">Associate Degree</li>
              <li id="diploma-technology" data-related="professional,specialist">Diploma in Technology
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="professional" data-related="associate-degree,diploma-technology">Professional roles
              </li>
              <li id="specialist" data-related="associate-degree,diploma-technology">Specialist roles
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="education-level four-years-college"><span>4 Years College</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="bachelors-degree" data-related="specialist,manager">Bachelor's Degree</li>
              <li id="bachelor-arts" data-related="manager">Bachelor of Arts</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="specialist" data-related="bachelors-degree,bachelor-arts">Specialist roles</li>
              <li id="manager" data-related="bachelors-degree,bachelor-arts">Management roles</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="education-level six-years-college"><span>6 Years College</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="masters-degree" data-related="expert,consultant">Master's Degree</li>
              <li id="mba" data-related="expert,consultant">MBA</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="expert" data-related="masters-degree,mba">Expert roles</li>
              <li id="consultant" data-related="masters-degree,mba">Consultant roles</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="education-level six-plus-years-college"><span>6+ Years College</span></td>
          <td class="credential">
            <ul>
              <li id="doctorate" data-related="expert,researcher">Doctorate</li>
              <li id="phd-science" data-related="expert,researcher">PhD in Science</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="career">
            <ul>
              <li id="expert" data-related="associate-degree,bachelors-degree,doctorate">Expert roles
              </li>
              <li id="researcher" data-related="doctorate,phd-science">Research roles</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
<svg id="arrows" aria-hidden="true"></svg>




The last row works fine for me in the snippet.

However, I believe the problems are with small screen devices, which require scrolling down to view the content of the last row table. @Barmar

You're right. When I reduce my window height, I see the problem.

Yes. Do you have any ideas about what the problem could be? :( @Barmar

I haven't looked at the code, but my guess is that it has something to do with how you calculate the parameters of the SVG used to draw the arrow. It's being cropped wrongly when there's a scroll bar.

if you have any solution for it, Can you kindly check?  i will really appreciate it @Barmar

As I said, I haven't read the code, and I don't really plan on it. SVG and CSS are not my area of expertise.
